# How to get a build triggered only for pattern specified in the GitRepo resource in JFrog Pipelines?

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

The files include, exclude regex for a GitRepo resource are getting ignored. This is the resource definition I’ve created:

```yaml
  - name: platform_pr
    type: GitRepo
    configuration:
      gitProvider: myGithub
      path: dev/helm-values
      files:
        include: ^templates\/(pipelines)\/*.+$
      branches:
        include: ^master$
      buildOn:
        commit: false
        pullRequestCreate: true
        tagCreate: false
      cancelPendingRunsOn:
        newCommit: false
        pullRequestUpdate: true
```

I don't want the build to be triggered when PR has files in that specific folder. This is not woking as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that in your yml you have specifically disabled builds for a commit:  `commit: false`.
Unfortunately this files inclusion or exclusion filter only applies to commit events, and not pull requests, tags, or releases:

Please refer to this documentation of [GitRepo Resource](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/GitRepo) for more information.

[image]